# Win32 GetSysColor(): Many colours now say: Windows 10 or greater: This value is not supported

Tags: winapi

Background: I am trying to reimplement Qt widget "QSizeGrip" as a custom control using the native Win32 C API.  Ref: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsizegrip.html

Super zoomed screenshot from GIMP:

[image]

From the official docs for `GetSysColor()` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsyscolor, many colours now have the warning: "Windows 10 or greater: This value is not supported."

Example: `COLOR_BTNFACE` -- This was my original choice for the background.

What three system colours should I use on Win10+ to re-create this Qt widget?

For the most modern solution, my guess: Call `HTHEME GetWindowTheme(hWnd)`, then call `HBRUSH GetThemeSysColorBrush(HTHEME, int iColorIdFromGetSysColor)`, but I don't know which `iColorId` values to choose.

Comment: That doesn't mean it no longer works, it means that Microsoft no longer wants to hear anybody complain about it.  What's new about Win10 is its support for high-contrast and dark mode themes.  The one thing you have to do, if you opt to support them, is verify that it still looks okay when the user selected one of those themes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-windows-themes

Comment: I'm not sure how accurate those annotations are. `COLOR_BTNFACE` is definitely still used in places; e.g. the background color for a standard Win32 dialog box.

Comment: The classic way of doing this is to call `DrawFrameControl` with `DFCS_SCROLLSIZEGRIP`. If you want the themed variant, call `DrawThemeBackground` with either `SBP_GRIPPERHORZ` or `SBP_GRIPPERVERT`. As others have said, what the MSDN docs now say for `GetSysColor` is errant nonsense. But you don't want to recreate this one pixel at a time using system colors anyway.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for the tip.  With your comment I was able to find `SBS_SIZEGRIP` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/scroll-bar-control-styles
It was very hard to write a custom widget to emulate Qt's `QSizeGrip`.  <sad face>  Oh, Win32.

Comment: Ah, yes. If you want the actual Win32 control, then definitely use a Scroll Bar control with the `SBS_SIZEGRIP` style. I had understood your question as asking how to re-create it. If you have the option of using the *actual* Win32 control, always prefer that. You'll never get the re-creation to quite match the original.